# Lock-free data structures

Tags: c, concurrency, lock-free

Can someone point me to an easy to understand implementation of lock-free data structures (pseudo-code is fine) that only use low-level atomic instructions like test&set and compare&swap. I'm trying to learn how they work, but everything I've seen is way more complex than what I want. I'm specifically looking for linked lists, queues, and stacks.

It'll be awesome if I can get a C implementation.

Comment: What does "easy to understand" mean? Lock-free programming is a subtle business, and what's easy depends on how much you understand about concurrency in the first place. Also, you need to specify requirements like the number of producer and consumer threads, since you get entirely different implementations depending on those parameters.

Comment: I'm basically looking for the bare minimum, correct code/pseudo code (not suffering from something like ABA) with some comments and/or explanation as to why it's done in a certain way.

Comment: You may read this http://www.drdobbs.com/lock-free-data-structures/184401865

Comment: I wrote a [detailed blog post](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2014/solving-the-aba-problem-for-lock-free-free-lists) about solving the ABA problem for lock-free free lists. You may find it interesting (it's considerably simpler and better explained than my usual lock-free code, since it concentrates on exactly one small problem).